# Knitr: Only show result without anything else

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I can't seem to figure this out..

in R Studio with an rhtml file, I want this:

```
<!--begin.rcode test <-1  end.rcode-->
```

To look like this in the html output:

1

But it currently looks like this:

```
## [1] 1
```

Basically looking to build an html page around this.. So all the extra divs and code generated by the knitr notation need to be excluded.

racking my head on this one.

Comment: Do you mean you want just a literal `1` to be printed? `results='asis' will output just the raw result.

Comment: Try putting `cat(1)` instead of `1`.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll - Yes that's correct, tried that though, didn't work. Showed "[1] 1" (removed hashtags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `echo` controls the display of code
- `results` controls the output of the code evaluations
- `message` controls the messages
- `warning` and `error` controls warnings and errors from the code evaluations.

  ````
  ```{r echo = FALSE, results = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE}

      # some code

  ```
  ````

Comment: Is that valid rhtml?