# Rmarkdown: how to change error messages from R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm writing in Rmarkdown. My datas are a matrix and a data frame. The issue is that the user selects three options to visualize the plot. For the first selection both datas are degraded as equal rows. For the second and the third selection the user selects one of the columns in both datas for the plot. For some selections it works fine but when there is no value in one of the selected columns it gives an error. How can I print a message like "There is no value for the selections" instead of an error?

Comment: Set error = true and use trycatch to get the error message http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649224/knitr-only-show-result-without-anything-else/38649355#38649355

Answer (score 0):

You can create an "output hooks". "Output hooks are a series of functions that take a piece of output as the input (typically a character vector), and return a character vector to be written to the output document." ([from the RMarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html) for more details).

In your case adding a chuck before the code chunk where you want to replace the message.

````
```{r setuphook, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(
   error = function(x, options) {
     if (startsWith(x, "The message to replace"))
        return("There is no value for the selections")
      else {
         return(x)
      }
   }
)
```
````

Please note: I did not test this code and you have to replace the string that identifies the message you want to change. Maybe [this post](https://selbydavid.com/vignettes/alerts.html) can be of further help, too. It is based on a markdown file that creates a hook. You can download and inspect it if you have further questions.